# Star Wars Eclipse-Class Super Star Destroyer

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I've been looking into the specs of the Eclipse dreadnought built by the Empire in pre-Disney SW canon, and cannot seem to find specifications for the shield class anywhere. It is clear that the shields and hull were significantly modified over the Executor to enable the Eclipse to ram other ships, but I would like to be able to at least approximate the shielding systems it employed. Anyone have thoughts on what shield class would be reasonable given the Executor has two ISD-72x deflector shield generator domes? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

[Dark Empire Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire_Sourcebook), a supplement for [Star Wars: The Roleplaying Game](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game), gives the following game stats for *the Eclipse*:

> **Hull:** 15D+2
>
> **Shields:** 11D+1

For the comparison, [Imperial Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Sourcebook_(Second_Edition)) (2nd edition), also by [West End Games](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/West_End_Games), gives the following stats for a Super Star Destroyer (*the Executor*):

> **Hull:** 10D
>
> **Shields:** 8D

This would make the hull of *the Eclipse* about 56% and the shields about 40% tougher than the ones of *the Executor*.

This is all Legends, of course.

Comment: Since the Eclipse is Legends, it hardly matters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity for non RPG types, what does 11D +1 mean? Sum of 11 D6 rolls add 1 to total?

Comment: @Jontia Exactly!

Comment: Makes you long for a D20.

Comment: Thanks! That makes for a good comparison. I guess I'll just have to guess as to what type of shielding that means in the star wars universe :)